# Zend Framework background service / worker

Tags: zend-framework, service, background-process, directory-structure

I'm wanting to create a background worker for a ZF application I'm working on but I'm baffled not as much about the software architecture but more of the filesystem architecture.

The worker would be triggered by a controller to perform some tasks and then the controller would check up on the status of the worker so this bit has been covered.

From the folder structure point of view where should these the code for the worker sit in?

```
application/
  models/
  services/
    worker/
      application/ --> code for the worker (standard ZF structure)
      worker.php   --> entry-point to the worker
```

Or

```
application/
  controllers/
    WorkerController.php
  models/
    Worker/
      Class.php
      Class2.php
  services/
    worker.php --> entry-point to the worker
```

Bear in mind the configuration of the main application and the worker are almost identical (especially same db connection credentials, autoloading settings) and the worker would need to access the main application's models.

Any advice or opinions would be appreciated.

Many thanks,
Angel

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that the worker component has a full ZF app structure (controllers, etc) and that the main app will make MVC requests into that component? And that the client request to the main app will wait on the worker to complete before returning a response to the waiting client?

Comment: Well, the worker *can* have the full ZF app structure (example1), and that's what I'm trying to establish - if it should indeed have the ZF app structure. The main app will *not* make MVC requests directly into that component but it will be able to display the status of the worker through the information obtained by a "status" table in the db. The worker will be triggered with via a cronjob that will check if there are any jobs running or kick off new jobs. I hope this helps, if yes I will update the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the worker is triggered via cronjob, then you *could*  make the worker component a module, so it has its own controllers, views, etc. Then - as @MonkeyMonkey notes - your commandline script could make MVC requests to that module.

But it seems to me that this worker component might function more naturally as a service, a class containing functionality that gets invoked by your cron-triggered cli script. ZF-based cli scripts - optionally using `Zend_Console_Getopt`, which is pretty cool - can use the same config and Bootstrap class,  selectively bootstrap resources (some might not be required for the cli-based task), and use the same autoloaders as the standard MVC app.

As you note, these workers will update a status table that would be accessible to the web-facing portion of the app, so those pages can read/render the status on request.

As for the filesystem structure of that, you could name these service classes something like `Application_Service_MyWorker` stored in the file `application/services/MyWorker.php`. Perhaps even push down further using something like `Application_Service_Worker_MyWorker` stored in `application/services/Worker/MyWorker.php`, though this latter might require adding another resource-type entry into the resource autoloader, similar to the way that mappers and DbTable-based models are defined in `Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader`.

Comment: Thanks for your input. So the second approach in my question is closer to what you suggest. I assume that in general we want to avoid adding "applications" within "applications". Only thing I need to do now is convince the software architect that his approach (app-in-app) is rather radical and we should go with my suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

MVC is not only helpful in web environments (Apache), you can use it for "background workers" as well (the view is your console), you just need to add a cli.php or something, handle cli arguments (module, controller, action), create the request object and pass it to the dispatcher.

So how ever your triggering of the background worker works (exec?), call your newly create cli.php and enjoy the features of your zf application (configuration, autoloading, ..).

For short, I can't tell you how exactly a cli.php would look like, but I found this tutorial:
[Using Zend Framework from the Command Line](http://webfractor.wordpress.com/2008/08/14/using-zend-framework-from-the-command-line/)

Important object for you: Zend_Controller_Request_Simple